# Python 3.6 -- Selenium Trying to click on the "Sign in" button on Youtube

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Python code, trying to access https://www.youtube.com/ and select/click the "Sign in" button:

```
from selenium import webdriver


browser = webdriver.Chrome()
browser.get('https://www.youtube.com/')

#Trying to select "Sign in" button
browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="button"]').click()
# Also tried .find_element_by_css_selector('#button')
```

CMD returns error:

```
C:\Users\shawn>%Python36% %projects%\Youtube\Main.py

DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:12229/devtools/browser/bd345ec5-f3af-48a0-a834-ac3ce7832917
[5944:128:1226/174147.900:ERROR:service_manager.cc(157)] Connection InterfaceProviderSpec prevented service: content_renderer from binding interface: blink::mojom::ReportingServiceProxy exposed by: content_browser
[5944:128:1226/174147.933:ERROR:service_manager.cc(157)] Connection InterfaceProviderSpec prevented service: content_renderer from binding interface: blink::mojom::ReportingServiceProxy exposed by: content_browser
[5944:128:1226/174148.434:ERROR:shader_disk_cache.cc(238)] Failed to create shader cache entry: -2
```

Can anybody explain the above error, and what is happening here? If you could also advise as to the correct way to go about this using Selenium, I would be very appreciative!

Comment: Which chrome driver you are using ?

Comment: Should be v2.34 as I downloaded it only a couple of days ago. Not sure how to check the version from here though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you were trying to locate the `WebElement` with text as **SIGN IN**, the `xpath` you have used as in **`browser.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="button"]')`** doesn't identifies the `WebElement` uniquely. There are **`30`** such `WebElements` on the page matching this particular `xpath`.

### Solution :

The solution would be to construct an unique `xpath` for the `WebElement` as follows :

```
browser.find_element_by_xpath("//yt-formatted-string[@class='style-scope ytd-button-renderer style-brand']").click()
```

Comment: Yep, that fixed it. I didn't really know how to use xpath properly. I ended up using XPath Helper (chrome extension) to locate the full xpath.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following code (it's working for me):

```
browser.find_element_by_css_selector("#button>#text.style-scope.ytd-button-renderer.style-brand").click()
```

Hope it helps you!

Comment: Almost working, seems that it clicks the button for a privacy reminder instead. Mind if I ask where you found the css selector from? When I copy directly from console in chrome I only get #button.

Comment: @ShawnR., what do you mean "almost working"? I am using FirePath (for testing) and created CSS selector with some tweaks from there.

Comment: I mean the code technically works, but is clicking the wrong button. I'm thinking I might have some issue with my selector.

Comment: @ShawnR., so, if my answer was helpful -- accept it, please. Thanks.

Comment: @ShawnR., `id` locator is used globally. So, you need to identify your element more precisely. If you any question -- ask, I will try to help you!

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need to use some sort out explicit wait in order for the element to be clickable e.g:

`element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedCondition.element_to_be_clickable((By.xpath, “xpathId”)));`

```
element.click();
```